# Reading data from /sdb1

Tags: python, linux, disk

My OS (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) is installed on my SSD at /dev/sda1, and I have some data stored in /dev/sdb1. How do I perform Python I/O operations with this? I've tried the following code:

```
with open('/dev/sdb/file.txt','r') as f:
    f.readlines()
```

But it throws the following error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/sdb'`

Or:

`NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/dev/sdb1/Quick Heal/INFO.DAT'`

How can I read files from /sdb1?

Comment: if you have a filesystem on it: mount it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to read the file you need to mount the filesystem first:

```
sudo mkdir /media/data
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/data
```

Afterwards you should be able to read the data using:

```
with open('/media/data/file.txt','r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        print(line)
    ...
```